# Video Duration not set correctly (exoplayer2)

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x

Using exopler2 I have no problem playing the video with subtitle,but the seek bar doesn't show any thing and the video duration doesn't appear 
if I remove the subtitle code and set only the video source every thing work fine ,but I need to add sub title 
this is my code

note : I am using m3u8 video and srt  for subtitle

[image]

```
    //  Create the player

    player = ExoPlayerFactory.
            newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);


    // Bind the player to the view.
    //simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

    // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new
            DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this,
                    "exoplayer2example"), bandwidthMeter);


    //FOR LIVESTREAM LINK:
    // MediaSource videoSource =new HlsMediaSource(videoUri,dataSourceFactory,1,null,null);
    MediaSource videoSource = new
            HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).
            createMediaSource(videoUri);

    player.prepare(videoSource);

    //time = player.getDuration();
    // Log.d("TTTTTTT", String.valueOf(player.getDuration()));
    //Build the subtitle MediaSource.
    Format textFormat = Format.createTextSampleFormat(null,
            MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP,
            null, Format.NO_VALUE, Format.NO_VALUE,
            "ar", null, Format.NO_VALUE);


    MediaSource subtitleSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource.Factory(
            dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(subtitleUri,
            textFormat, C.TIME_UNSET);
    //merging the video with subTitle
    MergingMediaSource mergedSource = new MergingMediaSource(subtitleSource, videoSource);
    //prepare video with sub title
    player.prepare(mergedSource);
    //set the player to view
    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    //auto play
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem with the MediaSource order when creating MergingMediaSource

```
MergingMediaSource mergedSource = new MergingMediaSource(subtitleSource, videoSource);
```

It should be like this

```
MergingMediaSource mergedSource = new MergingMediaSource(videoSource, subtitleSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

Exoplayer gives you very good facility to do this
just by setting `default id` - `"exo_duration"` to your textview and now you don't need to do anything

Using this id,exoplayer set video duration automatically to textview.

I'm also posting some code to save your time for Exo player

```
<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_prev"
style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_rew"
style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_next"
style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Next"/>
```

**Update:**
I forgot to mention some more information about this:

> *when you give `id's` to buttons for `rewind`, `forward` and others as shown in example above, you will no longer need `findViewById` and not even setting `clickListeners`, you even don't need to apply `style`(according to me)..*

**Another Thing:**

> using two button like given below is difficult to handle for visibility and click events:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play" />

<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause" />
```

but there's one solution for that:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play_pause" />
```